# Connect to MS Access using c++

Tags: c++, ms-access

I am developing a c++ application, which uses MS Access 2000 (back end database).
What is the best method to communicate with the database.

I can see a variety of options in msdn like

ODBC
OLEDB
DAO (Data Access Object)

From the below link, Microsoft says ACE engine should be used to communicate with Access 2007.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc811599.aspx#Ac2007DevelopingSolutions_Overview

Whether ACE engine can be installed in windows xp ??? so that my application can support both MS-Access 2000 and MS-Access 2007.

By the way, the application have to be ported to Linux. Is that possible to connect Access database from linux ?? (application in linux and database in windows)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OLEDB / ADO is the best on Windows, but if you need to port to Linux and don't want to re-write all of the db access stuff, I'd stick with ODBC.

Comment: What Linux ODBC driver do you recommend for connecting to an Access database file?